# In Vitest, how do I assert that a console.log() happened?

Tags: vitest

The question's in the title. With Jest it was `console.log = jest.fn()`. How do I get and analyse the console output of the code I'm testing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
import { afterAll, describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';

describe('should mock console.log', () => {
  const consoleMock = vi.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => undefined);

  afterAll(() => {
    consoleMock.mockReset();
  });

  it('should log `sample output`', () => {
    console.log('sample output');
    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('sample output');
  });
});
```

Comment: exemplary answer

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76042978/in-vitest-how-do-i-assert-that-a-console-log-happened/76271250#76271250) [@Yokozuna59](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16476610/yokozuna59)!

For others, if you still want to see the console log output, just define:

```js
const consoleSpy = vi.spyOn(console, 'log')
```

without the `mockImplementation()`.